# sort order of boost::weak_ptr after expiring?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-smart-ptr

For `boost::weak_ptr` the `operator<` is defined, so that it can be used in associative containers.

My question is: Is the sort order of several `weak_ptr` objects stable even when some of them change to a refcount of zero? Doesn't that mess with containers like `std::set`?

Example:

```
using namespace boost;
shared_ptr<A> sptrA1(new A);
weak_ptr<A> wptrA1 = sptrA1;
weak_ptr<A> wptrA2;

{ // begin Scope 1
    shared_ptr<A> sptrA2(new A);
    wptrA2 = sptrA2;
    assert(wptrA1 < wptrA2); // assert #1
}
assert(wptrA1 < wptrA2); // assert #2
```

- Will assert #2 always hold true if assert #1 is true?
- Is `wptrA2` in the same state before and after the Scope 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the current implementation of `boost::weak_ptr`, `operator<` compares a pointer to an internal reference-count-tracking structure. This structure is not freed until all strong *and weak* references are removed, so it remains safe to use `operator<` even if the pointed-to user data has been freed due to a lack of strong references.

Comment: Interesting. I was confused by the documentation of use_count in http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm. It states "Returns: 0 if *this is empty" however according to your answer the reverse (*this is empty if it returns 0) is not true, right? (If empty is defined as the state obtained from default constructing a weak_ptr.)

Comment: I haven't made any statements about what `use_count` does here :) That said, the internal reference counting structure keeps two counts - one for strong references only (when it hits zero, the pointed-to-object is destroyed) and one that includes both strong and weak references (when it hits zero, the reference-counting structure is destroyed). The `use_count` function might be looking at the strong-count-only one, but I haven't investigated at all, so verify for yourself. :)

Answer (score 2):

Read about weak_ptr comparision [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1590.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use std::owner_less. This compares the pointer of the use count, not the pointer itself. For example:

```
typedef std::weak_ptr<int> IntWPtr;
std::set<IntWPtr, std::owner_less<IntWPtr> > m_set;
```

Comment: interesting, however this is a C++11 feature which I cannot use at the moment.